# Custom taxonomy rewrite using tax name instead of rewrite slug

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, taxonomy

I Created a custom taxonomy for my `projects` custom post type.

```
function projects_taxonomy() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'              => __('projects Categories'),
    'singular_name'     => __('project Category'),
    'search_items'      => __('Search project Categories'),
    'all_items'         => __('All project Categories'),
    'parent_item'       => __('Parent project Category'),
    'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent project Category:'),
    'edit_item'         => __('Edit project Category'), 
    'update_item'       => __('Update project Category'),
    'add_new_item'      => __('Add New project Category'),
    'new_item_name'     => __('New project Category'),
    'menu_name'         => __('project Categories'),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects', 'with_front' => true)
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
  );
  register_taxonomy('projects-category', 'projects', $args);
}
```

The problem is the taxonomy rewrite is not working correctly and links to tax archive pages look like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/projects-category/first-cat/
```

instead of (what i expect):

```
http://www.domain.com/projects/first-cat/
```

I tried regenerating htaccess file through permalinks settings a few times. and also checked my syntax with wordpress codex and it seems okay. does it need to be enabled somehow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the `rewrite` argument defined inside the `$labels` array, move it out to the `$args` array:

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'projects', 'with_front' => true)
);
```

Comment: Foolish of me to expect it working like that! thank you very much for the help Milo